# How to match and remove occurrences from a file using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am new in Python and I am trying to to get some contents from a file using regex. I upload a file, I load it in memory and then I run this regular expression. I want to take the names from the file but it also needs to work with names that have spaces like "Marie Anne". So imagine that the array of names has this values:

```
all_names = [{name:"Marie Anne", id:1}, {name:"Johnathan", id:2}, {name:"Marie", id:3}, {name:"Anne", id:4},{name:"John", id:5}]
```

An the string that I am searching might have multiple occurrences and it's multiline.

```
    print all_names # this is an array of id and name, ordered descendently by names length 
    textToStrip = stdout.decode('ascii', 'ignore').lower()
    for i in range(len(all_skills)):
        print all_names[i]
        m = re.search(r'\W' + re.escape(unicode(all_names[i]['name'].lower())) + '\W',textToStrip)
        if m:
            textToStrip = re.sub(r'\W' + re.escape(unicode(all_names[i]['name'].lower())) + '\W', "", textToStrip, 100)  
            print "found " +  all_names[i]['name']
    print textToStrip
```

The script is finding the names, but the line `re.sub` removes them from the list to avoid that takes "Maria Anne", and "Marie" from the same instance, it's also removing extra characters like "," or "." before or after.

Any help would much appreciated... or if you have a better solution for this problem even better.

Comment: what exactly are you using re for?

Comment: On one hand I'll need to save the ids for later processing, on the other hand I need to remove all the occurrences every time I find a name, because if I the script finds "Maria Anne", and I don't remove all the occurrences, later on the same name will also be interpreted 2 more time as Maria and another as Anne.

Comment: so you want the value changed to `""`?

Comment: yes, that's the plan, that's what I am doing on this line:
textToStrip = re.sub(r'\W' + re.escape(unicode(all_names[i]['name'].lower())) + '\W', "", textToStrip, 100)

But for some reason, if the line says "Monday Maria Anne, and ..." it removes "Maria Anne," and I don't need that "," to be removed

Answer (score 0):

The characters on both sides are deleted because you have \W included in re.sub() regexp. That's because re.sub replaced *everything* the regexp matches -- the way you call re.sub.

There's an alternate way to do this. If you wrap the part that you want keep in the matched regext with grouping parens, and if you call re.sub with a *callable* (a function) instead of the new string, that function can extract the group values from the match object passed to it and assemble a return value that preserves them.

Read documentation for re.sub for details.